# DROP EXTENSION then CREATE EXTENSION of updated custom extension installs previously dropped extension

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to update a custom extension in pgsql with the updated SQL & control files.
My process was to drop the extension & then re-create it after installing the updated files & deleting the old in /share/postgresql/13/extension/ directory.

When I run:

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS extension CASCADE;
```

It drops it.

Then I proceed to copy the new SQL & control files in /share/postgresql/13/extension/

Then I create the new extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION extension SCHEMA test;
```

When I check List of extension, it shows the old extension is installed & when I check in database, I still see the old functions.

When I run

```
ALTER EXTENSION extension UPDATE;
```

I get
`NOTICE:  version "1.0" of extension "extension" is already installed`

If I try to run

```
ALTER EXTENSION extension UPDATE to "1.1";
```

I get
`ERROR:  extension "extension" has no update path from version "1.0" to version "1.1"`

Is there a cache that I need to clear in postgres to add my new extension?

Comment: The usual approach is to use `alter extension ... update` after installing the new version.

Comment: When I run 
`ALTER EXTENSION extension UPDATE;`
I get 
NOTICE:  version "1.0" of extension "extension" is already installed
If I try to run
`ALTER EXTENSION extension UPDATE to "1.1";`
I get 
ERROR:  extension "mas_heb" has no update path from version "1.0" to version "1.1"

Comment: Then you have not updated the extension files on disk, assuming there really is a version 1.1.